# How to show all edges

Tags: modeling

This is Blender 101, but I can I just confirm that (Edit mode with faces, Faces > Triangulate faces) is the equivalent of Undissolve Edges - if such a menu item existed. And such a thing as un-dissolve.

[image: show all edges on cube]

How to show the edges that exist, but have been dissolved into quads on the default cube.
(Avoiding key words like hidden and visible/invisible) for obvious reasons.

Comment: The faces of the default cube are quads, until render-time (whichever renderer, including viewport). They can be non-planar. They are not triangles until made so... ( I was just about to post @Leander's answer :)  )

Answer (score 1):

Add a Wireframe node in the shader and go into shaded mode.

[image: wireframe shader]